# C# code to connect CRM saved views

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm

I followed this link "https://prabirchoudhury.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/retrieve-microsoft-crm-2011-data-using-fetchxml-and-web-service/" and connected to CRM.

On that link below is the code to connect to user created View.

```
string fetchXml = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false' count='100'>
 <entity name='account'>
 <attribute name='ownerid' />
 <attribute name='name' />
 <attribute name='accountnumber' />
 <attribute name='accountid' />
 <order attribute='accountnumber' descending='true' />
 <link-entity name='systemuser' to='owninguser' alias='mainuser'>
 <attribute name='systemuserid'/>
 <attribute name='domainname' />
 <attribute name='fullname' />
 </link-entity >
 </entity>
 </fetch>";
```

If you see I had to pass XML code to get data from CRM, however I just want to pass view name and get the data in the form of csv file instead of passing XML code. I have done the same in Powershell but I need to do the same in C# code.

The reason I want to just pass view name is because tomorrow user will do any modification in the view and I don't have to touch the code if the user makes any changes so I need to make this dynamic, secondly after getting the data how can I create csv file on buffer(without creating physically on machine)and then export to any cloud based service.

Comment: you might be interested in [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt656691.aspx)

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: Why Reflection? He just needs to `Serialize` his objects to XML and call the applicable web service?

Comment: @harshu288 Can you provide the code on how you are talking to the web service. I know you provided the link, but your implementation details would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method that will get you the FetchXML from a saved view, based on the name of the view and the name of the entity:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;
using System.Linq;

private string getFetchXml(IOrganizationService svc)
{
    var query = new QueryExpression
    {
        EntityName = "userquery",
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("userqueryid", "name", "fetchxml"),
        Criteria = new FilterExpression
        {
            FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
            Conditions =
            {
                new ConditionExpression
                {
                    AttributeName = "name",
                    Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                    Values = {"My View"}
                },
                new ConditionExpression
                {
                    AttributeName = "returnedtypecode",
                    Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                    Values = { "account" }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var result = svc.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    var view = result.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
    var fetchXml = view.GetAttributeValue<string>("fetchxml");
    return fetchXml;
}
```